# Register client event in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a `RadComboBox` that is populated in code behind and a button that registers the event of `RadComboBox.onClientSelectedIndexChanged`.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox
    ID="rcbUsers"
    runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>

<telerik:RadButton
    ID="btnReg"
    runat="server"
    AutoPostBack="False"
    OnClientClicked="btnReg_OnClientClicked"
    Text="Register Event"></telerik:RadButton>
```

In *JavaScript*, I have this code:

```
function btnReg_OnClientClicked(sender, args) {
    var rcbUsers = $.find('<%= rcbUsers.ClientID %>');

    rcbUsers.selectedIndexChanged = rcbUsers_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

function rcbUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
    console.log('selected index changed');
}
```

but the `rcbUsers_SelectedIndexChanged` will not trigger when I change the item in `RadComboBox`. Is this the right syntax?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add your `handler` like this (using `add_selectedIndexChanged` api):

```
$find('<%= rcbUsers.ClientID %>').add_selectedIndexChanged(function(sender, e){ 

     // do something
})
```